# Php final keyword giving fatal error when adding in parent class

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to add `Final` keyword in `db` class for prevent the some query functions in other classes. But this final keyword giving me fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Class user may not inherit from final class (db)
```

### Php Code

```
final class db{
    private $connection;
    public function __construct () {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $dbname = 'studentsyetem';      
        $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }else{
            echo 'Connected';   
        }
    }
    public function insert($u_name,$u_password,$u_level){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (u_name, u_password, u_level, date_added) VALUES ('".$u_name."', '".$u_password."', '".$u_level."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
        mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql);
    }
}

class user extends db{
    public function child() {
        echo 'user';
    }
}
$user = new user();
echo $user->child();
```

Without `final` keyword code working fine, I wanted to know where i'm doing wrong. Can any one guide me I will appreciate.

Comment: You should define the methods as final, not the class itself as then you cannot extend it any more. Note that then the method cannot be overwritten, it is not blocked from usage. If you need that, you should declare the method `private`

Comment: @jeroen Thanks,  Means i can only add `final` keyword on that method which i want to prevent in extended classes

Comment: No, you should declare these as `private` methods. Depending on what you mean with *prevent* of course...

Comment: My means is that there is `insert` function in parent class so if someone try to create again same function in child class then php should not allow to do

Comment: Then it should be `final` :-)

Comment: @jeroen Sure, but i will have to add on method `final funcion insert(){...}` not on class correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Classes with Final Keyword cannot be inherited. Any child class should not inherit final class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you an example it explans why the error occurs. `final` method cannot be overwritten, nor can you with `abstract` nor `extends` BUT with `trait`.

```
class foo {
   final public function Func() {
       echo "foo::Func() created";
   }
}

class bar extends foo {
   public function Func() {
       echo "foo::Func() re-written"; // it fails
   }
}
```